# Sorting is different between two Excel files

Tags: excel

I have two Excel files of similar data and when I sort the File Name column from A to Z for both excel sheet. Both starts with different name. After sorting both excel sheet, I got this.

Excel A

```
File Name
123
48
(Document 01)
```

Excel B

```
FileName
(Document 01)
123
48
```

Comment: The second range looks sorted Z-A...

Comment: It is not possible to replicate. In both cases, if you are not selecting the header, then you get 48 - 123 - (Document 01) as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If the "numbers" are actually formatted as text, Excel B is the sort result.  If the "numbers" are actually numbers, Excel A is the sort result.  (When sorting both files A-Z.)  You didn't say how you want the sort to end up, so I suggest checking both files to make sure the columns are formatting the "numbers" the same.